# object multidymentional arrays, properties and conditions

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, struct, conditional-statements

```
// just some enum
enum Player
{
    One,
    Two
}

// just a structure with 2 properties.
struct justSomeStructure
{
    char ID {get;set;}
    Player playerID {get;set;}
}

// just some arrays.
justSomeStructure[] collection = new justSomeStructure[9];

// just a string array with number sequences.
string[] justSequences = new string[10]()
{
    "123", "345", "735" ect ect.
}


public bool isThereAMatch()
{
    // do stuff here.
}
```

this code isnt written in visual i wrote it in the editor so sorry if it doesnt look good but its just for demonstration.

what i want to achieve;

get each string from justSequences in turn.
get all the justSomeStructure items where ID == one of the char in the string sequence.

from this result, check if all playerID properties in the items share the same Player enum value.

if so return true.

okay, so my question;

how best can i do this, whats your suggestions?

Comment: this code will never compile. you should give us working code at least. your array initialisers are really really weird

Comment: I would store an numerical id into an `int` or at least a `byte`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: sorry im not the best, and it isnt meant to be working code, its just a written example of the type of items i have and their properties, and what i want to achieve.

Comment: Something like this should work :   return (from seq in justSequences where (from data in collection where data.ID == seq select data.playerID).Distinct().Count() == 1).Any();